# Test interface implementation for simple calculator

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, calculator, implementation

I would like to test if my implementation of an interface is done correctly or not, but just don't really know how.

If you could give me a hint regarding my implementation (something missing maybe?), would be very much appreciated.

It's supposed to be a simple calculator.

```
public interface ICalculator {

/** Returns a+b */
public int add(int a, int b);

/** Returns a-b */
public int subtract(int a, int b);

/** Returns a*b */
public int multiply(int a, int b);

/** Returns minimum of a and b */
public int min(int a, int b);

/** Calculate cross sum */
public int crosssum(int a);
}    


public class Calculator implements ICalculator {

public int a
public int b

public int add(int a, int b) 
    System.out.println("ICalculator - add " + a + " und " + b);
    return a + b;
    }

public int subtract(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println("ICalculator - subtract " + a + " und " + b);
    return a - b;
}

public int multiply(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println("ICalculator - multiply " + a + " und " + b);
    return a * b;
}

public int min(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println("ICalculator - min " + a + " und " + b);
    if (a < b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}

public int crosssum(int a) {
    System.out.println("ICalculator - crosssum " + a);
    int sum = 0;
    while (0 != a) {
        sum = sum + (a % 10);
        a = a / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Where/for what exactly do you need hints? Please be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the @Override annotation above all of your methods that your are overriding from your interface(not needed, but good practice to allow others to see what is overridden), semi colons are missing after your declared ints, finally your add method is missing a beginning { brace.

Here is what I did to make it work, you have some formatting issues for the prints, and you should declare all your variables private and provide getter/setter methods if required.

```
private int ans;
@Override
public int add(int a, int b) {
   ans = a + b;
   System.out.println("ICalculator - add " + a + " und " + b + "= " + ans);
   return ans;
}
@Override
public int subtract(int a, int b) {
   ans = a -b;
   System.out.println("ICalculator - subtract " + a + " und " + b
     + "= " + ans);
   return ans;
}
```

An even simpler variant you can just make your methods void and do this:

```
@Override
public void add(int a, int b) {
System.out.println("ICalculator - add " + a + " und " + b "=" + (a + b);
}
```

Here is all i did to test to see if your methods are working:

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     Calculator cal = new Calculator();

     cal.add(5, 4);
     cal.subtract(6, 0);

   }
}
```

This should allow for a good start for you to fix your formatting, and test your other very simple methods, and make corrections to them.